# How do I change EDITOR to be Pico in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I can’t get [Mercurial (`hg`)](http://mercurial.selenic.com) to use `pico` as my EDITOR when I’m using [`fish`](http://fishshell.com) shell.

I’ve tried using this and other variations, but nothing seems to help:

```
set -U EDITOR pico
```

`hg commit` will always open `vi` as the editor, and I do not want that.

**UPDATE:** Adding `setenv EDITOR pico` to the file `~/.config/fish/config.fish` did what I wanted.

Comment: Do you have `VISUAL` set?

Comment: thanks! `setenv` worked for me too when trying to set `$BUNDLER_EDITOR`

Comment: You should make your solution a proper answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: Note that `setenv` is just a compatibility alias for `set -gx`. In the long wrong you'll be better off avoiding the use of such shims and doing things "the fish way"; e.g., `set -gx EDITOR pico`.

Answer (score 31):

This is the canonical way to do so

```
set -Ux EDITOR pico
```

- U for universal variable
- x to export it

Comment: pico is same as nano !!!

Answer (score 12):

This [FAQ](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html) suggests adding `set -gx EDITOR pico` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 7):

You can also set a default editor just for git, which will ignore your default setup:

```
git config --global core.editor pico
```